# How can i display the number of items in a list when i press a button

Tags: python, list, function, textbox

```py
def count_books():
    count = 0
    for i in lists_of_saved_Books:
        count += 1
        if count == 10:
           Book_count_window.insert(1.0, f'{count}')
           tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", '10 books is a milestone to celebrate:D!')
           count +=1
        else:
            Book_count_window.insert(1.0, f'{count}')
            count +=1
```

I created this function above to increase count by one when ever another book is saved in another list. I want it to display a notification whenever it reaches 10 and continue to add 1 whenever another book is saved other wise. It is not displaying the number of books (the number of items in lists_of_saved_Books), although im sure its not an input problem since with this original function, the number of books still display n the texbox:

```py
def count_books():
    count = 0
    for i in lists_of_saved_Books:
        count += 1
    Book_count_window.insert(1.0 ,f'{count}')
```

This is the code that appends the bookname(tensach) after a button is pressed

```py
def get_info():

    if len(Book1.get("1.0", "end-1c")) == 0  and len(Book2.get("1.0", "end-1c")) == 0 and len(Book3.get("1.0", "end-1c")) == 0 :

        Book1.insert(1.0, f'Pages: {sotrang.get(1.0, END)}')
        Book1.insert(1.0, f'Author:{Tacgia.get(1.0, END)}')
        Book1.insert(1.0, f'Genre: {tttheloai.get(1.0, END)}')
        Book1.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
        lists.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
        lists_of_saved_Books.append(tensach.get(1.0, END))

        Book1.config(state = DISABLED)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Success!')

    elif len(Book1.get("1.0", "end-1c")) >= 1  and len(Book2.get("1.0", "end-1c")) >=1 and len(Book3.get("1.0", "end-1c")) >=1 :
                     tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", ' Finish all the books bruh')

    elif len(Book1.get("1.0", "end-1c")) > 1 and len(Book2.get("1.0", "end-1c")) > 1 :
         Book3.insert(1.0, f'Pages: {sotrang.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book3.insert(1.0, f'Author:{Tacgia.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book3.insert(1.0, f'Genre: {tttheloai.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book3.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
         lists.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
         lists_of_saved_Books.append(tensach.get(1.0, END))

         Book3.config(state=DISABLED)
         tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Success!')

    elif len(Book1.get("1.0", "end-1c")) >= 1 and len(Book3.get("1.0", "end-1c")) >= 1:
         Book2.insert(1.0, f'Pages: {sotrang.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book2.insert(1.0, f'Author:{Tacgia.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book2.insert(1.0, f'Genre: {tttheloai.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book2.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
         lists.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
         lists_of_saved_Books.append(tensach.get(1.0, END))

         Book2.config(state=DISABLED)
         tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Success!')

    elif len(Book2.get("1.0", "end-1c")) >= 1 and len(Book3.get("1.0", "end-1c")) >= 1:
                     Book1.insert(1.0, f'Pages: {sotrang.get(1.0, END)}')
                     Book1.insert(1.0, f'Author:{Tacgia.get(1.0, END)}')
                     Book1.insert(1.0, f'Genre: {tttheloai.get(1.0, END)}')
                     Book1.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
                     lists.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
                     lists_of_saved_Books.append(tensach.get(1.0, END))

                     Book1.config(state=DISABLED)
                     tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Success!')

    elif len(Book1.get("1.0", "end-1c")) >= 1 and len(Book3.get("1.0", "end-1c")) == 0:
          Book2.insert(1.0, f'Pages: {sotrang.get(1.0, END)}')
          Book2.insert(1.0, f'Author:{Tacgia.get(1.0, END)}')
          Book2.insert(1.0, f'Genre: {tttheloai.get(1.0, END)}')
          Book2.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
          lists.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
          lists_of_saved_Books.append(tensach.get(1.0, END))

          Book2.config(state=DISABLED)
          tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Success!')

    elif len(Book1.get("1.0", "end-1c")) ==0 and len(Book2.get("1.0", "end-1c")) == 0 and len(Book3.get("1.0", "end-1c")) >= 1 :
         Book1.insert(1.0, f'Pages: {sotrang.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book1.insert(1.0, f'Author:{Tacgia.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book1.insert(1.0, f'Genre: {tttheloai.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book1.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
         lists.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
         lists_of_saved_Books.append(tensach.get(1.0, END))

         Book1.config(state=DISABLED)
         tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Success!')

    elif len(Book1.get("1.0", "end-1c")) ==0 and len(Book3.get("1.0", "end-1c")) == 0 and len(Book2.get("1.0", "end-1c")) >= 1 :
         Book1.insert(1.0, f'Pages: {sotrang.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book1.insert(1.0, f'Author:{Tacgia.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book1.insert(1.0, f'Genre: {tttheloai.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book1.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
         lists.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
         lists_of_saved_Books.append(tensach.get(1.0, END))

         Book1.config(state=DISABLED)
         tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Success!')

    elif len(Book2.get("1.0", "end-1c")) ==0 and len(Book3.get("1.0", "end-1c")) == 0 and len(Book1.get("1.0", "end-1c")) >= 1 :
         Book2.insert(1.0, f'Pages: {sotrang.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book2.insert(1.0, f'Author:{Tacgia.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book2.insert(1.0, f'Genre: {tttheloai.get(1.0, END)}')
         Book2.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
         lists.insert(1.0, f'Book name: {tensach.get(1.0, END)}')
         lists_of_saved_Books.append(tensach.get(1.0, END))


         Book2.config(state=DISABLED)
         tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Success!')


    tensach.delete(1.0, END)
    tttheloai.delete(1.0, END)
    Tacgia.delete(1.0, END)
    sotrang.delete(1.0, END)

lists_of_saved_Books = []
```

I have create an empty list for this

Answer (score 1):

Because your `count` will be odd ever time you check.

You have increment for it two times. Remove it and you'll get your notification.

Also, don't duplicate code in `if` and `else` blocks without reason.

```py
def count_books():
    count = 0
    for i in lists_of_saved_Books:
        count += 1
        Book_count_window.insert(1.0, f'{count}')
        if count == 10:
           tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", '10 books is a milestone to celebrate:D!')
```

Comment: can you explain it further:(

Comment: it still does not work, do you need further code:(?

Comment: @COBAKIET, it could depend on how `lists_of_saved_Books` is used. Edit your question and add code that changes it.

Comment: i edited it, hope u understands, its just getting inputs fmo another text box and insert it into the list

Comment: @COBAKIET, And is this line `Book_count_window.insert(1.0, f'{count}')` produces correct output in your window?

Answer (score 0):

the answer (im so dumb)

```py
def count_books():
    count = 0
    for book in lists_of_saved_Books:
        count += 1
    Book_count_window.delete(1.0, END)
    Book_count_window.insert(1.0 ,f'{count}')
    if count == 10:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations!", "You have saved 10 books!")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).